# Gdata signed request error: "Unknown authorization header"

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I have a problem with Updating and Deleting events using signed requests. Inserting events works just fine. But when Updating and Deleting I receive an "Unknown authorization header" 401 error.

For ALL three operations I first generate the client like this:

```
$client = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient();  
$client->setAuthSubPrivateKeyFile('certificates/gcalkey.pem', null, true);
$client->setAuthSubToken($session_token);
$gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
```

To Update an event I use this:

```
$eventOld = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventEntry($eventUri);

$eventOld->title = $gdataCal->newTitle('NEW NAME');
try {
    $eventOld->save();
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) { print_r($e); exit; }
```

And it gives me the "Unknown authorization header" error. But the same code, using unsigned requests, works.

Where might be the problem? I tried modifying $eventUri to both https and http, but it seems it does not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this 401 error message too, creating the client and service the same way. It can retrieve a list of calendars, but fails when retrieving an event feed.

Has this worked for you before? It might not be officially supported [yet](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.gdata.authsub.html).

Comment: This is unfortunate. However I know a web app, that when you authorize your google calendar to sync with it, does not give you that warning "This website is registered with Google to make authorization requests, but has not been configured to send requests securely. We recommend that you continue the process only if you trust the following destination:" . Which means it used a key/certificate and then received a secure token.

How might that be? That warning is really a turn off for users.

Comment: I agree, that's why I tried to get a secure version working. Apparently it was [working](http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2008/09/secure-authsub-using-zend-php-library.html), or it still works and we're both missing something. Someone had a 401 error on that blog post, but that fix didn't work for me.